# cron daemon with curl command is sending empty emails

Tags: php, linux, email, curl, cron

my cron daemon is sending empty emails after job execution.

This is the cron job

`curl -m 900 --connect-timeout 900 -s 'http://example.com/job.php' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36' --compressed -o ~/cronlog && mailx -s "example.com cron job executed" myemail@gmail.com < ~/cronlog`

I receive emails but they are empty.

If I execute the above command from terminal the content of ~/cronlog is in the email.

Job is executed as current user, so "~" should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to crontab?

If so, i'd use the cron scheduler to email yourself. 
It will email anything the script outputs.

Under crontab, or /etc/cron.d/local:

```
MAILTO=example@mail.com

* * * * * your/cron/path
```

Comment: I already set MAILTO, mail arrives but the problem is the empty body

Comment: have you tired executing the script by hand? Any output from the script should be sent out in the email. Unless you've got `&> /dev/null`

Comment: Yes, the output of the script is succesfullty included in the email body

Comment: the problem occurs only during cron execution